# escape from inner repeat loop in casperjs

Tags: javascript, loops, phantomjs, repeat, casperjs

i have one nested **casper.repeat** in **casper.repeat** loop. and i need escape from inner and continue from first **casper.start().repeat(500...** when one element appears.. i scrape site where i pass pages and in one of this pages(i dont know exactly which one) one element can appear and i need to to break this loop and continue from start point.
well this is my code:

```
casper.start().repeat(500, function() {

if(counter==11) {
    page_counter++;
    counter=0;
}

casper.open('http://my.ya.ru/clubs_rating.xml?p=' + page_counter);

var links = this.getElementsInfo('dl.info dt a');
this.echo('Opened page: ' + this.getCurrentUrl());

casper.repeat(40, function() {

 //here i need make **waitFor** to check element every time////////
//and if it's here - break loop and go to start point/////////////

if(innercounter==19) {
    ipagecounter=ipagecounter+20;
    innercounter=0;
}
```

Comment: Look at the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/27360109/581414

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
casper.waitForSelector('#your_selector_id', function() {
    test.assertExists('#your_selector_id', "We've find this element\^_^/!");
}, function () {
    this.echo('Wasn't found in 10 seconds!');
}, 10000);
```

Or look at https://github.com/yotsumoto/casperjs-goto
Goto is a peace of sadness, but I believe might be useful.

```
casper.start();
casper.repeat(500, function() {
    casper.open('http://my.ya.ru/clubs_rating.xml?p=' + page_counter);

    casper.label( "LABER_FOR_BREAK" );

    var counter=0;
    casper.label( "LOOP_START" );

    casper.then(function(){
        //check selector
        if( /*true selector assertion*/ ){ 
            this.goto( "LABEL_FOR_BREAK" ); 
        };
    });

    casper.then(function() {
        counter++;
        this.echo( counter );
    });

    casper.then(function() {
        if( counter<41 ){ this.goto( "LOOP_START" ); }
    });
});

casper.run( function() {
    this.dumpSteps( true );
    this.exit();
});
```

Does this make sense?

Comment: A simple `waitForSelector` doesn't solve the problem. If you suggest *Goto* then you should also provide sample code.